# Issue with getting bulleted list from docx

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to get bullet list from docx using C#, however, instead of bullet number or symbol, the output gets a weird symbol or rectangle with a question mark inside "", instead of a bullet. Following is the code snippet I am using to get bullet value, but it is not working:

```cs
Application word = new Application ();
Document doc = new Document ();
object fileName = @"D:\testing\Sample_2.docx";

// Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
object missing = System.Type.Missing;

doc = word.Documents.Open (ref fileName,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++) {
    string bullet = doc.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.ListFormat.ListString;
}
((_Document) doc).Close ();
((_Application) word).Quit ();
```

Comment: The bullet can't be rendered in the debugger visualizer.

Comment: thanks Amy, i need to read text from a word document, including bulleted text, is there some way to achive it?

Comment: You *have* achieved it. You have the character.  The debugger can't render it.

Comment: when this bullet is written in plain .txt file it becomes and empty rectangle.

Comment: actualy the output text of this service is an input to a text editor where the same issue occures, so i guess it is not just an issue of debugger visulizer. May be any kind of formating needs to be applied?

Comment: Wthout knowing the font characteristics of the bullet symbol you're processing it's a bit difficult, but most likely this symbol is Unicode, not ANSI, which means it can only be displayed correctly in an environment that supports "rich" Unicode. If you need to display in a text editor you probably need to substitute some other character for the bullet. You should also consider that longer text, that breaks to a new line, will no longer display with a "pretty" hanging indent in a text editor...

Comment: thanks Cindy, i have tried it by changing encoding format in my code as:-

doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing,Encoding.Unicode, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


but in vain :-(

Comment: Tip: If you want to get someone's attention you need to preface their name with a @ so that StackOverflow sends a notification. There's no other way for us to "watch" discussions in which we're participating. Pure chance that I happened to look in here...

Comment: My previous observation has nothing to do with the encoding Word uses - specifying anything when opening the Word document, where the bullet is displaying correctly, won't affect you trying to extract that bullet and display it in another interface. 1) make a screen shot of Word text with this bullet and insert it into your question using the [edit] link.

Comment: 2) In Word, click in a line with the bullet then in the Ribbon click the dropdown next to the "Bullets" symbol; from the menu select "Define new bullet"; in the dialog box click "Symbol". The Symbol dialog box that appears should show you the *font* that's used to display the bullet and the ANSI or Unicode value in that font. The environment where you want to display this bullet needs to format the character in this font. Or, as I said before, you need to change the bullet to something that environment does support.

Comment: If, for example, I have the bullet ● Word formats an ANSI character with the Symbol font. If I change the bullet in Word to Unicode 25CF (in VBA ChrW(&H25CF) ) then it copy/pastes correctly for me here and in Notepad.